# Small tree containing smaller trees

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, computer-science

Given $n$, what is the smallest number $N=N(n)$ with the property that there exists a tree on $N$ (unlabelled) vertices that contains a copy of every tree on $n$ vertices?

That such $N$ must exist is easy to see in a number of ways.

Comment: [OEIS sequence A004401](http://oeis.org/A004401) gives the corresponding numbers if the containing graph isn't restricted to be a tree.